# Everything is forbidden in a wamp server

Tags: apache, wamp

I'm using a wampserver on my local network and whenever I try to access any page i get a 403 Forbidden error. I can access everything from localhost but nothing from any other computers. This hasn't been happening before. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

WAMPserver is configured as a single user developer environment, to protect beginers from the possibility of being hacked. So by default Apache will only accept connections from the machine it is running on.

If you want to access WAMPServers Apache from another PC on your network, if you are sure there is no external connections possible ( you have a router and port 80 is not port forwarded) then all you need to do is :-

```
wampmanager -> Put Online
```

This will change the Apache config to allow any ip to access Apache and restart the Apache.

If you want to be more specific about who can access Apache then manually change the `httpd.conf` file like so

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

find this section

*Apache 2.4.x*

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
```

and add a specific ip address or the first 3 of the 4 quartile of your subnet to allow anyone on your internal network access

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
    Require ip 192.168.1
```

*Apache 2.2.x*

Change from

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

To

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 ::1
    Allow from 192.168.1
```

Comment: I am such an idiot. For some reason when the server is offline then the WAMP icon is still green. So I didn't even think to check if it was still online. I just started plowing through tons of config files.

Comment: The `Online` and `Offline` dont mean Apache is working or not. They mean `Online=Apache is accessible from all the universe` and `Offline=Apache is only accessible from this PC` It purely denotes Apache's security setting. If the icon is GREEN, that means the Apache service is started.